# SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED not working correctly in Windows

Tags: rendering, tiles, sdl2, pixel-art, fog-of-war

I am developing a 2D tile-based game and I have a series of transparent tiles which I use to simulate a fog of war effect. This seems to work well in Linux but I am having trouble understanding why it does not work in Windows.

The transparent layer is drawn on top of the map layer in Linux. If I set the rendering to `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE` the issue does not crop up in Windows. But I am stumped as to why this happens. Does anyone have experience with this? The first image is that of the rendering in Linux, the second is in Windows 10.

[image]

[image]